# spring data mongo No property b found on entity class when retrieving entity by Id

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, lombok

I have a parent class that has some shared fields and a child class that extends it.

```
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
@Data
public abstract class MultiTenantAuthoredDocument {

    @Indexed
    private String tenantId;

    @CreatedDate
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private LocalDateTime lastModifiedDate;
}


@Document(collection = "users")
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@ToString(callSuper = true)
 public class User extends MultiTenantAuthoredDocument {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    @Indexed
    private String password;

    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private String userName;

    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Indexed
    private List<UserRole> roles;

    @Builder.Default
    private boolean enabled = false;

}
```

However when running my unit tests, I get an unexpected exception when I do a findById and there's a result found namely:
`No property b found on entity class be.moesmedia.erp.users.domain.User to bind constructor parameter to!`
As I have no clue where property b is coming from it's pretty difficult to see what I'm doing wrong. 
If anyone can help me point out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

So I've figured out what was going wrong, Lombok generated a constructor that accepted an Object with the properties for the SuperBuilder class. Once I added `@NoArgsConstructor`to both the child and parent class, it works like a charm.

Comment: Yeah, that's the reason I don't like `@Data`. You might think that a required-args constructor (in this case no-args) should be present already, but `@Data` only generates one if there is no other constructor yet. And `@SuperBuilder` generates one.

Comment: Aha, so that's the exact reason! Thx for clearing that out :)