# MongoDB Method threw 'org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException' exception

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I have the following model

```java
@Builder
@Data
@Document(collection = "overdue")
public class MGOverdue {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Overdue>> overdueList;
}
```

the `repository.findById()` throws the following exception

```
Method threw 'org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException' exception
```

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: No property b found on entity class .<package>.receipt.Overdue to bind constructor parameter to!
```

Any suggestion please

Answer (score 0):

I had to add `@NoArgsConstructor` to my model **Overdue**. It's similar to this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/53210768/7691891